# C# WPF Change Listbox Item Size

Tags: c#, wpf

I wanna create metro style listbox. I need XAML style code for Listboxitem. I wanna change Listboxİtem size runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You can use styles.  Add the following XAML to a Window:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="MyListBox" DisplayMemberPath="ItemText">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ItemHeight}"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ItemWidth}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind, populate the list by binding some data items to the list box like this:

```
    public class ItemData
    {
        public int ItemHeight { get; private set; }
        public int ItemWidth { get; private set; }
        public string ItemText { get; private set; }
        public ItemData(int itemHeight, int itemWidth, string itemText)
        {
            ItemHeight = itemHeight;
            ItemWidth = itemWidth;
            ItemText = itemText;
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyListBox.ItemsSource = BuildItems();
    }

    private System.Collections.IEnumerable BuildItems()
    {
        yield return new ItemData(20, 200, "First");
        yield return new ItemData(40, 300, "Second");
        yield return new ItemData(60, 100, "Third");
    }
```

When you run the app you will see that the different items have different sizes.

Comment: Will whoever voted down this answer please explain why it fails to accomplish the goal of changing the ListBoxItem size at runtime?

Comment: @Vishera, if you like my answer, please accept it.  I think it gives you the insight you need to accomplish your goals.